# How to align images with subcaptions with different lengths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

I have three tikz pictures aligned horizontally, but their captions have different lengths, which causes the image with longer caption to rise instead of being aligned with the others, like this (image c is not aligned with the others):

[image]

The source code for this image is:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[black, fit={(0.5,0.5) (3.2,1.2)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (a) {\small Error detection};
                \node[black, fit={(0.5,1.2) (3.2,1.9)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (b) {\small Error correction};

                \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
                (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.9) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small SW};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{Software-only fault tolerance architecture.}
        \label{fig:swonly}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[black, fit={(0.5,0.5) (3.2,1.2)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (a) {\small Error detection};
                \node[black, fit={(0.5,1.2) (3.2,1.9)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (b) {\small Error correction};

                \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
                (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.9) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small HW};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{Hardware-only fault tolerance architecture.}   
        \label{fig:hwonly}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[black, fit={(0.5,0.5) (3.2,1.2)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (a) {\small Error detection};
                \node[black, fit={(0.5,1.2) (3.2,1.9)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (b) {\small Error correction};

                \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
                (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.2) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small HW};
                \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
                (0.5,1.2) -- (0.5,1.9) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small SW};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{Hardware/Software cross-layer fault tolerance architecture.}
        \label{fig:hwsw}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Fault tolerance architecture approaches.} 
\label{fig:architectures}
\end{figure}
```

I wanted all images aligned but I don't know how to do it. Besides, I wanted the text inside the nodes to be centered vertically. If you could help I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: please extend your code sniped to complete small document. solution is depend on page layout which now is not known.

Comment: @Zarko I'm using the llncs template, so it is hard to do that.

Comment: no, it is not hard at all. you need only to strip-down your document to this image and in preamble preserve only necessary packages/libraries. until you will not do this, i cant complete my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[black, fit={(0.5,0.5) (3.2,1.2)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (a) {\small Error detection};
\node[black, fit={(0.5,1.2) (3.2,1.9)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (b) {\small Error correction};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.9) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small SW};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Software-only fault tolerance architecture.}
\label{fig:swonly}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[black, fit={(0.5,0.5) (3.2,1.2)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (a) {\small Error detection};
\node[black, fit={(0.5,1.2) (3.2,1.9)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (b) {\small Error correction};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.9) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small HW};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hardware-only fault tolerance architecture.}
\label{fig:hwonly}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[black, fit={(0.5,0.5) (3.2,1.2)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (a) {\small Error detection};
\node[black, fit={(0.5,1.2) (3.2,1.9)}, inner sep=0pt, draw] (b) {\small Error correction};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.2) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small HW};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,1.2) -- (0.5,1.9) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small SW};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hardware/Software cross-layer fault tolerance architecture.}
\label{fig:hwsw}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fault tolerance architecture approaches.}
\label{fig:architectures}
\end{figure}
```

**addendum:**

off-topic exercise for drawing `tikzpicture` :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                fit,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\tikzset{
every node/.append style={font=\small},
box/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
              draw, %text width=26mm, 
              inner sep=3mm, outer ysep=0},
 BC/.style = {decorate,
              decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
              pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
              post=moveto, post length=1pt,
              raise=1mm},
              thick,
              pen colour={black}},
        }

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [box] {\nodepart{one} Error detection
                 \nodepart{two}  Error correction};
\draw [BC] (a.south west) -- node[left=2mm] {SW} (a.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Software-only fault tolerance architecture.}
\label{fig:swonly}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [box] {\nodepart{one} Error correction
                 \nodepart{two}  Error detection};
\draw [BC] (a.south west) -- node[left=2mm] {HW} (a.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hardware-only fault tolerance architecture.}
\label{fig:hwonly}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [box] {\nodepart{one} Error correction
                 \nodepart{two}  Error detection};
\draw [BC] (a.south west) -- node[left=2mm] {HW} (a.one split west);
\draw [BC] (a.one split west) -- node[left=2mm] {SW} (a.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hardware/Software cross-layer fault tolerance architecture.}
\label{fig:hwsw}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fault tolerance architecture approaches.}
\label{fig:architectures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: both solutions not work with `llncs`, since this document class doesn't wok with `caption` and `subcaption` packages. so i wonder, do you really produce showed image with use id this document class.

Comment: Thank you, this works! And I don't know but I am using `llncs` with `subcaption` package and it is working. Maybe they updated their template?

Comment: i try to use `llncs`, but it give me error that it is not compatible with `subcaption` package.  anyway, you now can see, how important is to provide complete small document. you should (in future) help us to help you and also gives other members of site, who has similar problems, more information what you try so far.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `\subcaptionbox`. I modified how you make the diagrams a bit as well.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikzset{
  box/.style={black,draw,font=\small,minimum height=7mm,minimum width=2.6cm, outer ysep=0},
  my brace/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm,mirror,raise=2pt}}
}
\subcaptionbox{%
  Software-only fault tolerance architecture. \label{fig:swonly}
}[0.32\linewidth]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[box] (a) {Error detection};
                \node[box,anchor=north west,at={(a.south west)}] (b) {Error correction};

                \draw [my brace]
                (a.north west) -- (b.south west) node [midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small SW};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{%
  Hardware-only fault tolerance architecture.\label{fig:hwonly}
}[0.32\linewidth]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[box] (a) {Error correction};
                \node[box,anchor=north west,at={(a.south west)}] (b) {Error detection};

                \draw [my brace]
                (a.north west) -- (b.south west) node [midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small HW};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{
Hardware/Software cross-layer fault tolerance architecture.\label{fig:hwsw}
}[0.32\linewidth]{%
           \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[box] (a) {Error correction};
                \node[box,anchor=north west,at={(a.south west)}] (b) {Error detection};

                \draw [my brace]
                (a.north west) -- (a.south west) node [midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small SW};
                \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.8mm,mirror,raise=1pt}]
                (b.north west) -- (b.south west) node [midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\small HW};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\caption{Fault tolerance architecture approaches.} 
\label{fig:architectures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```